# How to hold Jenkins SCM polling while a job is runniong

Tags: version-control, jenkins, queue, perforce

So I inherited a slightly odd setup (Changing it will be time consuming):

I am using Jenkins with SCM (Perforce) polling, but the triggered job does not use the SCM Workspace in any way except the triggering itself. Then the build pulls the latest revision and builds from that. This setup works, but it creates an unnecessary backlog:

```
10:00 submit Rev#100001
10:05 SCM polls this and queue a build job#101
10:06 job#101 start (will take ~2H)
10:30 submit Rev#100002
10:35 SCM polls this and queue a build job#102
11:00 submit Rev#100003
11:35 SCM polls this and queue a build job#103
12:00 job#101 exits
12:01 job#102 start (will take ~2H)
```

*Now assuming no new submits, `job#103` is an unneeded repeat of `job#102`.*

---

**Update:** From [@Slav](/users/1720943/slav)'s [answer](/a/25509083/110488) I realized that I was not clear enough. The fact that the SCM trigger is not related to the pulling of the code base, cause this abnormality:

```
job#101 reports that it was triggered by Rev#100001 and builds from Rev#100001
job#102 reports that it was triggered by Rev#100002 and builds from Rev#100003
job#103 reports that it was triggered by Rev#100003 and builds from Rev#100003
```

This also explains why there are more then one queued run: From Jenkins'es POV, each queued build is different.

---

I wish to eliminate this backlog.

This can be done by e.g.

- When job#101 is running don't poll SCM (best option)
- When job#103 is queued - remove job#102 if it didn't started yet.
- any other way?

Is this possible? And if so how?

Comment: Even after your update, I still don't understand why you consider jobs 102 and 103 to be "unneeded". The code has changed, so don't you need to build the code with the new changes? If you don't want to build every change, you could consider making your builds scheduled by times, i.e., "we build the code 4x a day, at 6 AM, noon, 6 PM, and midnight".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is happening? I've never seen more than 1 queued run, even if there are multiple triggers in between.

When I had scenarios where a build was taking longer than the polling interval, easiest way to manually fix it is by disabling the job after it had started (and re-enabling it after it completed), but that's only useful in case of exceptions and manual intervention.

If you want this for automation purposes, you should look at "quiet period" advanced options (under Job Configuraiton).

Comment: AFAIK, "quiet period" does the wrong thing in my case. I need it to wait N seconds after build start, and before next SCM poll; instead it waits after SCM poll and before build starts.